# How to automatically generate script using command line in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server Management Studio, there is a "Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard" context menu option that automatically generates the insert statement script for the table's data.

In my case, I have access to only query on a database using command line. Meaning I am unable to access the "Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard".

Is it possible to achieve something similar using pure SQL or T-SQL command line?

Comment: One option would be Powershell, if you have access to that. [Automated Script-generation with Powershell and SMO - Phil Factor](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/)

Comment: Here's a nice write up for what is and is not possible https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95262/get-object-script-in-sql-server-via-t-sql

Answer (score 0):

That is a basic SQL build the insert based on system views:

```
DECLARE @sqlinsert AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @tbl AS VARCHAR(128)='dbo.mytable'

SET @sqlinsert  = 'DECLARE 
'

SELECT @sqlinsert = @sqlinsert + ' 
@ins_' + c.name + ' ' + t.name
 + IIF(t.max_length>=8000,'('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),c.max_length) +')','')+ ','--c.column_id, c.name,c.system_type_id,t.name,c.max_length,t.max_length,c.*
FROM sys.tables a
JOIN sys.schemas b ON a.schema_id = b.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = a.object_id
JOIN sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id AND t.system_type_id <> 231
WHERE b.name+'.'+a.name = @tbl 
AND is_rowguidcol = 0 AND is_identity = 0 AND is_computed = 0
ORDER BY c.column_id

SET @sqlinsert = SUBSTRING(@sqlinsert,1,LEN(@sqlinsert)-1)

SET @sqlinsert = @sqlinsert + '
Insert Into ' + @tbl + ' ('

SELECT @sqlinsert = @sqlinsert + '
[' + c.name + '],'--c.column_id, c.name,c.system_type_id,t.name,c.max_length,t.max_length,c.*
FROM sys.tables a
JOIN sys.schemas b ON a.schema_id = b.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = a.object_id
JOIN sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id AND t.system_type_id <> 231
WHERE b.name+'.'+a.name = @tbl 
AND is_rowguidcol = 0 AND is_identity = 0 AND is_computed = 0
ORDER BY c.column_id

SET @sqlinsert = SUBSTRING(@sqlinsert,1,LEN(@sqlinsert)-1)
SET @sqlinsert = @sqlinsert + ') 
Values ('

SELECT @sqlinsert = @sqlinsert + '
@ins_' + c.name + ','--c.column_id, c.name,c.system_type_id,t.name,c.max_length,t.max_length,c.*
FROM sys.tables a
JOIN sys.schemas b ON a.schema_id = b.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = a.object_id
JOIN sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id AND t.system_type_id <> 231
WHERE b.name+'.'+a.name = @tbl 
AND is_rowguidcol = 0 AND is_identity = 0 AND is_computed = 0
ORDER BY c.column_id

SET @sqlinsert = SUBSTRING(@sqlinsert,1,LEN(@sqlinsert)-1)
SET @sqlinsert = @sqlinsert + ')'

SELECT @sqlinsert

--SELECT * FROM sys.types
```

Perhaps you may need some more filters/cases reading the sys views if your tables have specialties not covered.